# Problem add to pdf image file in directory

Tags: graphics, pdf, import

MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book} 

\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import} 

\graphicspath{ {ABC/} }

\newcommand{\circuit}[1]{
\begin{center}
\subimport{ABC/}{#1}
\end{center}}

\begin{document}

%\shorthandoff{=}\includegraphics{TR-1.pdf} %It's working.

\circuit{TR-1.pdf} % It's not working.

\end{document}
```

Output, **Text line contains an invalid character**. How can I do?

Comment: `import` is not meant for including graphics ;-) It just does basically the same thing as `\include` or `\input` for normal `.tex` code files, however, with remote paths and in a more refined manner.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I see.

Comment: You should only use the `center` environment in the document, not in the preamble.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unusual short answer from me:

The `import` package is 'only' suitable for importing/inputting/including subdocuments, which in turn might have basically any valid `LaTeX` code (few exceptions remain, of course).

It allows for setting remote paths but the `\subimport` or `\import` command cannot be used as a replacement for `\includegraphics` or `\includepdf` (package `pdfpages`) to import graphic or `.pdf` files.

It's still necessary to use `\includegraphics` for (ordinary) graphic files.